# how get the index of the minimum element of each row of matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix

I am attempting to write a code to find index of the minimum element of each row from the 'distance' matrix, excluding zeroes from the matrix.

Comment: How are your attempts coming along ?  Do share your code with us.

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/min.html have a look at the second output... also consider setting all your zeros to be `inf`

Comment: http://bit.ly/1aq19oE - that's how you can find information in the Internet by yourself.

Comment: @Mikhail - that link was very cool!

Comment: @Mikhail If you're going to criticize someone's SO question, please first read the question.  The OP wants the minimum element "excluding zeros" which is not the same thing as just the minimum element.

Comment: @dspyz Honestly, I did read the question. It's not too long. But I assume it is obvious to "Inf-out" zero elements prior to finding a min, as Floris did. And one using Matlab should be aware of its very basic functions. These facts together made me believe this is a poor-quality question and I should mock at it.

Comment: Inf-out is not a standard trick (go ahead and find me a link to even a single place where somebody Inf's out entries to keep them from being identified by min) nor is it necessarily the correct thing to do (as I mention in my answer, if the matrix is sparse this could result in an OOM error), so no it's not obvious, nor is it necessarily correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the distance matrix is a (large) sparse matrix, this problem is somewhat more nontrivial. The best approach is probably to subtract the (max value * 2) from each nonzero element in each row.  This seems ugly and hackish but I can't think of any other efficient way to solve it.

```
sub = max(0, max(myArray,[],2) * 2);
[i,j,v] = find(myArray);
v -= sub;
myArray = sparse(i,j,v);
[junk mi] = min(myArray,[],2);
```

EDIT: There are still precision issues if elements within a row have very different magnitudes. If this is the case, you can take negative inverses instead.  In this way, you're not combining magnitudes from different elements in the matrix (or with any constant)

```
posOnly = ~any(myArray < 0, 2);
[i,j,v] = find(myArray);
inds = posOnly(i);
v(inds) = -1 ./ v(inds);
myArray = sparse(i,j,v);
[junk mi] = min(myArray,[],2);
```

(Note the use of ~any(myArray < 0) rather than all(myArray >= 0) because (myArray < 0) is at least as sparse as myArray whereas (myArray >= 0) is not sparse)

Comment: Interesting thought - but by definition a sparse matrix doesn't have "zero elements"... "S = sparse(A) converts a full matrix to sparse form by squeezing out any zero elements". http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html

Comment: You've got it the wrong way around.  By assumption, most elements in a sparse matrix are zero.  "squeezing out any zero elements" means not storing them explicitly in memory.  Just because they're not stored doesn't mean they're not part of the matrix.  The objective of my code is to shift all the nonzero values in the matrix down far enough to make them negative.  You can't change the value of all the zero elements or you'll likely get an OOM error.  As an example, try your answer on a matrix generated by sprand(50000,50000,0.00001).  Then try my answer on the same matrix.

Comment: OK - I see what you did there. A more efficient ("slightly less hackish") solution is: `sub = max(M(:)) + 1; [~, mi] = min(spfun(@(x)(x-sub), myArray), [], 2);` . This way to compute `sub` is somewhat faster (no per-element multiplication, single `max` operation), I don't assign a return value to `junk`, and using `spfun` circumvents the whole `find-sub-sparse` thing. This assumes that `myArray` started out as sparse... otherwise my initial solution should work.

Comment: If the elements of myArray are very small or very large, adding 1 can cause a loss of precision and end up giving the wrong result.  What if all the values in one of the rows is between 0 and 1E-100?

Comment: You're probably right about spfun though.  I'm used to Octave where anything that's not compiled runs extremely slow so it's best to avoid things like spfun

Comment: Fair point about the loss of precision with the `+1`. You are obviously thinking about all the edge cases and that's really a great habit. In Octave, is it more efficient to do `max(max(a,[],2)*2)` or `2*max(a(:))`? I suspect the latter - unless it makes a copy of `a` because of the (implicit) reshaping operation... but that would be very poor design given it is an intermediate variable.

Comment: No, I'm not taking the max of the max.  I'm taking the max of each row and then maxing that vector with 0 (in case the row contains only negative terms).  So the result is still a vector, not a single entry.  Again, this avoids losing precision with floating point operations (namely when the rows have very different scales. ie if one row is in the range 0 to 1E-100 and another row is in the range 0 to 1 or something like that)

Comment: Of course, this can still cause problems if a single row contains values of wildly different magnitudes.  To fix that, I think you'd have to binary search the result (ie by repeatedly zeroing out all entries which are greater than half the max).  I imagine that 99.9% of the time that would be unnecessary though.  It does seem like there should be a better way still.

Comment: I figured out the better way and posted it as an alternative.  Take negative inverses whereever a row has only positive values

Answer (score 1):

Using Dan's hint:

```
myArray(myArray==0)=Inf;
[m mi] = min(myArray, [], 2);
```

The values of `mi` will be the index of the minimum element in each row. Note the minimum is taken along the second dimension (per dspyz's suggestion).

Comment: min(myArray') should be min(myArray,[],2) or it won't behave properly on an n by 1 array.